# Play Game Texture

Tags: game-engine

Whenever I apply texture to my game models in blender game, it won't display the texture and will either make it invisable or white. What should I do?

Comment: I suggest to post your question and your blend file on blenderartists.org. The information you currently provide is not sufficient to provide specific help. It might be better to post at least some screen shots (with some information about your setup).

Comment: Make sure you are in textured mode rather than solid mode.